ValueError: Input is in incorrect format
I'm encountering a persistent issue when running the StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline for an inpainting task. Despite passing inputs in the expected formats (both the image and mask are in PIL.Image.Image format with correct sizes), I keep receiving the following error:
ValueError: Input is in incorrect format. Currently, we only support <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'torch.Tensor'>

Here is the code:
@torch.inference_mode()
def generate_image_bytes(base64_img, request, prompt) -> dict:
    # Get a model from the pool
    model = model_pool.get_model()
    
    try:
        if base64_img is not None:
            img_data = base64.b64decode(base64_img)
            img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))

            print("Recieved image of size: ", img.size)
        
        img = img.convert("RGB")
        image_np = np.array(img)
        
        roi_points = [
            request["box"]["x1"],
            request["box"]["y1"],
            request["box"]["x2"],
            request["box"]["y2"],
        ]

        results = model["seg_model"](
            image_np, 
            device="cuda", 
            conf=0.6, 
            iou=0.9, 
            bboxes = roi_points,
            labels=[1],
            verbose=False    
        )
        black_mask = np.zeros_like(image_np[:, :, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
        for m in results[0].masks.data:
            mask = m.cpu().numpy().astype(np.uint8)

            orig_shape = results[0].masks.orig_shape
            resized_mask = cv2.resize(mask, (orig_shape[1], orig_shape[0]))

            black_mask[resized_mask == 1] = 255
        
        image_pil = Image.fromarray(image_np)
        mask_pil = Image.fromarray(black_mask).convert("L")

        print(f"Image size: {image_pil.size}, mode: {image_pil.mode}")
        print(f"Mask size: {mask_pil.size}, mode: {mask_pil.mode}")
        
        generator = torch.Generator(device="cuda").manual_seed(0)

        image = model["pipeline"](
            prompt=prompt,
            negative_prompt=IMG_INPAINTING_NEG_PROMPT,
            image=image_pil,
            mask=mask_pil,
            guidance_scale=8.0,
            num_inference_steps=50,
            strength=0.05,
            generator=generator,
        ).images[0]

        # Convert image to bytes
        bytes = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(bytes, format="PNG")

        return {"bytes": base64.b64encode(bytes.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")}


I tried viewing both images i.e image_pil and mask_pil and they have no problem. Their format and size is also same but I am still getting this error.

As a starting point I'd check the HuggingFace source code image_processor.py:45 which raises the exception. We see that, to avoid errors, 1 of 3 conditions must be met. The first is isinstance(images, (np.ndarray, torch.Tensor)) and images.ndim == 4. The second is isinstance(image, PIL.Image.Image) or isinstance(image, (np.ndarray, torch.Tensor)) and image.ndim in (2, 3). The third is relevant if passing lists of images. Can you check if your inputs meet these?

I checked it, the image is passing is_valid_image condition but mask image is not passing it, returns False. I checked the type of mask image before sending it to the pipeline it returned this:
<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>

If it's PIL.Image.Image this means it should pass the check isinstance(image, PIL.Image.Image). Please double check this. Then, it must also pass image.ndim in (2, 3). Does it pass this second condition?

mask_pil turns into NoneType when passed in the pipeline. I double checked it by printing the type before sending to the pipeline and also in is_valid_image function. Before pipeline:
type(mask_pil) => <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
In pipeline:
type(mask_pil) => <class 'NoneType'>

I modified the is_valid_image function like this to better understand what's happening:
    print(type(image))
    if isinstance(image, PIL.Image.Image):
        print("PIL Image")
    else:
        print("Not a pil image")
    return isinstance(image, PIL.Image.Image) or isinstance(image, (np.ndarray, torch.Tensor)) and image.ndim in (2, 3)

And I am getting this output:
True
<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
PIL Image
In valid image func
False
<class 'NoneType'>
Not a pil image


well it got fixed, I had to pass mask_image=mask_pil but I was passing mask=mask_pil
